# How to pass unique ID to multiple Datepicker in REACT?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using Clay UI Date Picker. I render multiple Date Picker when I select date it applies to all.

```
        const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
        <ClayForm.Group>
          <label htmlFor="">Date 1</label>
          <ClayDatePicker
            onValueChange={setValue}
            placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
            spritemap={spritemap}
            value={value}
            years={{
              end: 2024,
              start: 1997
            }}
          />

         <label htmlFor="">Date 2</label>
          <ClayDatePicker
            onValueChange={setValue}
            placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
            spritemap={spritemap}
            value={value}
            years={{
              end: 2024,
              start: 1997
            }}
          />
        </ClayForm.Group>
```

I try pass id and key in ClayDatePicker. But didn't work. Please help

Comment: Can you show where you passed id and key in ClayDatePicker?

Comment: Tried pass id and key as props in ClayDatePicker

Comment: The issue is with the props (value, onValueChange) in DatePicker. That's why when I select one date it applies to all. How to make it dynamically?

Comment: I believe we need to see the complete code, seems like a lot of code are missing.

Comment: consider an array [1,2,3,4,5]

I'm looping the array and render the datepicker. here it'll print for 5 times. when I try to add a date it's values applies to all because it shares the common value as props. 

return array.map(arr => {
  return  <ClayDatePicker
            onValueChange={setValue}
            placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
            spritemap={spritemap}
            value={value}
            years={{
              end: 2024,
              start: 1997
            }}
          />
})

I don't want to apply value to all 5 datepicker. How to fix this.

Comment: Use `value={someCondition ? value : null}` so it won't apply to all.